# Manipulating CP Elements List view with source filtering does not work for assets

Tags: assets, control-panel

I made a plugin which customize columns table view for all my elements and using a filter on the source :

Entries: **section**

```
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    // set fields for one section
    if ($source == 'section:8' )
    {
        unset($attributes['expiryDate']);
    }
}
```

User Groups : **group**

```
public function modifyUserTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'group:6' )
    {
        $attributes['unepRegionDelegateMember'] = Craft::t('Région');
    }
}
```

It is working great for these two but I got a problem with the assets source param, it just does not work, I tried **folder** as explained in Craft Doc but does not work:
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyAssetTableAttributes

Assets: **folder**

```
public function modifyAssetTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'folder:2')
    {
        unset($attributes['dateModified']);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
In fact my problem was that I was mistaken by the asset `sourceID` which has nothing to do with the `folderID` requested by the function `modifyAssetTableAttributes`. See what I mean here:

For **entries** or **user groups** you can find the ID in CP in the section/usergroup page, the CP page URL contains the ID:
`http://craft.dev/admin/settings/sections/5`
`http://craft.dev/admin/settings/users/groups/5`

But for the **assets** the ID in the url is not the folderID : 
`http://craft.dev/admin/settings/assets/sources/2`

SO MY REAL QUESTION IS:
Is there a function to retrieve the main folder ID from an asset source handle to do `$folderId = craft()->assets->source(‘asset-handle’)->id`
So we could easily use function `modifyAssetTableAttributes` and provide source filter `if ($source == 'folder:51’)`
On the same pattern as for section : `$sectionId = craft()->sections->getSectionByHandle('handle')->id;`

**ELEMENT MODEL + GETCRITERIA** 
I tried this
`$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);`
`$criteria->source = ‘asset-handle’;`
*But I dont see how to get to main folder ID after...*